# Ping a host specific times and store output in a file

Tags: batch-file, ping

I need to write a batch script that pings `google.com` 30 times and then writes the output to a `.txt` file. here is the code I am currently using:

```
@echo off

:LOOPSTART
ping google.com -t >> filename.txt 
goto LOOPSTART
```

Comment: Where's your limit of 30?

Comment: Please provide a specific question title! the current one is completely useless!

Comment: **Your question is off topic**. This is not an issue with your posted code not working as written and intended, it is an issue with your inability to read and understand the usage information for the command you're runnnig.

Comment: This actaully makes absolutely no sense. You are looking at doing a ping 30 times, pipe to a file, then return to the loop, so effectively you are pinging the site forever which would be exactly the same as `ping site -t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ping has an option to set the number of pings (see man ping)

```
ping -c 30 google.com > log.txt
```

or for windows I guess:

```
ping -n 30 google.com > log.txt
```

Comment: You mean option `-n`, don't you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried that and it comes back with Bad option -c.

Comment: -n works! fantastic thanks very much for all you help.

Comment: @DarylBaker, so essentially you didn't read the help file for the `PING` command?

Comment: Tag [tag:batch-file] is mainly Windows-related, that's why `-c` appeared wrong to me...

Answer (score 0):

The option to submit custom numbers of pings to a host with `ping` is `-n`:

> `-n` **count**      Number of echo requests to send.

Your command would be:

```bat
ping -n 30 google.com
```

If you want to ***redirect*** this to a file, use the **`>`** operator.

However, in your example, you make a continuous loop, so you need to ***append*** it. This, can be done using the **`>>`** operator.

- 'Redirect', means to erase the previous content of the file (if the file exists), and write the output of the command there (if file doesn't exist, create a new file).
- 'Append' means to redirect the output of a command to a file **without erasing the content of it**.

You may choose which suits better for you, but I think you should use `>>`. Your code will be:

```bat
@echo off

:loopstart
(ping -n 30 google.com)>>filename.txt 
goto loopstart
```

Read:

- https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html
- Output of `ping /?` in `cmd.exe`.

Comment: You do realise that your loop would end up doing pretty much the exact same as this line would do? simply because the loop returns directly, continuing the ping. `ping google.com -t>>filename.txt` ;)